# Cannot unfollow a tag that has no questions

Tags: bug, tags

So, I started following the [apple-pay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-pay) tag when it was announced by Apple.  But there's no activity for that tag (and there's little activity for the [applepay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applepay) tag, too).

Anyway, normally when you click on a tag, you go to its page, and a little animated box will appear when you hover over the tag, then you have the opportunity to no longer follow it (or to follow it).

This isn't happening for me.

Comment: Just go to your preferences-page (in profile, just click on your avatar), and do it there.

Comment: This is odd, please explain for all of us.  Why would you want to unsubscribe from a tag that has no activity at all?

Comment: @HansPassant Why would I need to explain for everyone why I want to unsubscribe from a tag?  Birds gotta fly...  Fish gotta swim...  Camels gotta carry water over long expanses of desert... And I gotta unsubscribe from that tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to go to the Favorite Tags sidebar on the front page of the site, click the "edit" link at the top, then remove any tags from that list. (Hover over the X in a gray circle on any tag. It will turn red and you can click it to remove the tag.)

[image: Favorite Tag Removal]